# Facebook graph's url not returning the right link

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, hyperlink

I am using a facebook share link in several spaces of my site, but with some images the post pushed on facebook wall's user doesn't display the image. The picture link is

http://mysite.org/files/campaign/image/originals/18/Sans%20titre-3.jpg

So I tried to input this link in facebook's debugger, and I get that [link](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http://primagora.org/files/campaign/image/originals/18/Sans%2520titre-3.jpg). The problem is that the corresponding open graph link is

```
http://graph.facebook.com/195459563930903 and the json which it's supporting is http://primagora.org/files/campaign/image/originals/18/Sans\u002520titre-3.jpg
```

Is it a facebook's cache issue ? (because I had to deal with the facebook's share name parameter that I had to escape, and the facebook's share wasn't working at all for this specific image whose name contained bad escaped white space)

Comment: try it with smaller image, maybe fb is just not supporting partial content or turn off sending partials on your web server

Comment: in fact, I use bigger images my site and it works very well. What do you mean by 'turn off sending partials on your web server'

Comment: Btw, I used the same image on my test server and it worked well, the image is supported

Comment: web servers can use header accept-ranges, and than a bigger file can be sent by parts not as whole over http, but as i said im not sure this is the issue, but at least you can try

Comment: How do you configure that ? Btw, I have bigger image that displays correctly when shared on my prod server. I kept on googling my problem and it seems that there is a trick about suppressing http://www in front of the url, would it help ?

Comment: so i assume thats not the problem then, can you please provide links of image/s which are working? maybe i can spot differences in those

Comment: here's my link to the prod site http://primagora.org/index.php?page=campaign&campaign_id=18 and to the test site http://sameditresfroid.fr/index.php?page=campaign&campaign_id=210. You'll the share button on the side bar (next to the twitter and google + share)

Comment: try removing special characters and spaces from your image names

Comment: Suppose my image has path {$image} (using smarty template engine), I already put {$image|escape:'url'}

Comment: rename file Sans%20titre-3.jpg lets says to Sans-titre-3.jpg

Comment: I cant' really do that because it is my prod server and it is some user's image...

Comment: that was not problem anyway, i tested it right now, it seems its too big, try to resize that image to smaller dimensions

Comment: ok weird because other images works properly, so you think I should configure something on my server (because the same file displays fine on my test server). If yes how can I parametrize it ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22759/discussion-between-derki-and-newben)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its mostly caused because image file is too big